# Quarkus nested group config not working in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

Mapping config to an object works fine for me with Quarkus in Kotlin (see https://quarkus.io/guides/config-mappings). However, as soon as I try to use a nested group I get an error saying that the PropertiesConfigSource does not map to any root. Why doesn't this work?

FooProperties.kt

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "foo")
interface FooProperties {

    interface Bar {
        fun baz(): String
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
foo.bar.baz=hello
```

SOLUTION:

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix="foo")
interface FooProperties {
    fun bar(): Bar
    interface Bar {
        fun baz(): String
    }
}
```

Comment: try this instead:

```@ConfigMapping(prefix="foo")
interace FooProperties {
    public Bar bar();
    interface Bar { ...}
}```

Comment: Since it's Kotlin and not Java I rewrote your code but it works indeed, thanks! I've added the solution for future reference.